# Does Glitter Dust become invisible if you cast Invisibility afterwards?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, invisibility

If you are affected by [glitter dust](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glitterdust) and then decide to become [invisible](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility), shouldn't the glitter dust become invisible and no longer outline the creature? The source of light still exists, and the light is visible, but you cant see the source of light anymore.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## You're not the first to wonder about this

The designers have known for a while that there are questions surrounding the scenario in which a creature affected by the spell [*glitterdust*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glitterdust) casts the spell [*invisibility*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility). *Pathfinder* lead designer Jason Bulmahn clarifies (to some extent) in this 2010 [thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kvto?Glitterdust-Effects):

> *Glitterdust* kills invisibility and all the rules that go with it.
>   *Glitterdust* has no effect on other forms of concealment.
>   *Glitterdust* also makes it very difficult to hide and might blind you.
>   That is all... (as it is currently worded).

If this is insufficient, you can read more in threads from [2011](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2n7db?Glitterdust#1), [2012](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pa05?Question-about-spell-Glitterdust#1), [2013](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pz6a?Invisibility-vs-Glitterdust#1), [2013](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pg55?Glitterdust-and-Invisible-Creatures#1), and [2014](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rczn?Glitterdust#1). (There are even more, but these seem most relevant.)

To summarize the most common reading:

#### Invisibility makes light *sources* but not the light *itself* invisible...

In fact, the spell [*invisibility*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility) says pretty much exactly that:

> Light, however, never becomes invisible, although a source of light can become so (thus, the effect is that of a light with no visible source).

Thus an invisible creature's torch still sheds light.

#### ...So invisibility makes [*glitterdust*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glitterdust)'s *dust* invisible but not the *sparkling*

The spell [*glitterdust*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glitterdust), a [conjuration spell of the creation subschool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Conjuration),  says that

> A cloud of golden particles covers everyone and everything in the area, causing creatures to become blinded and visibly outlining invisible things for the duration of the spell. All within the area are covered by **the dust**, which cannot be removed and **continues to sparkle until it fades**.

So the spell negates invisibility *because* the sparkling itself *doesn't* also become invisible.

Comment: There are some easy-to-poke holes in this (the idea of a torch being "invisible" but casting light is impossible unless you have intelligent photons, and glitterdust isn't clearly described as a light *source* — most of the description and common sense would imply that it's not) but I suppose at some point you just have to say "hey, magic". Invisibility is full of contradictions anyway.

Comment: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56363/what-happens-when-im-invisible-and-something-im-wearing-has-light-cast-on-it goes both ways on the matter, even WRT something that's obviously a light source :)

Comment: @hobbs *Pathfinder* is quite different from *Dungeons and Dragons, 5th Edition*. Further, while the *glitterdust* spell isn't a light source, as a conjuration (creation) school spell, the spell's effect creates the dust for the spell's duration, which is the source of the sparkle. (But I  totally agree that classic magical invisibility is bad science. `:-)` The *Wild Cards* novel series *did* have a character who could turn invisible but couldn't see if she turned her eyes invisible; that's about as science-y as I've ever seen invisibility get.)

Comment: @hobbs Who says there are photons in *Pathfinder*?  It's also possible if the correct physical description of the world is different, which it clearly is.

Answer (score 4):

The dust still glows, even when invisible;  which makes it really very easy to see where the dust is.  If it's all over an invisible creature, that creature is going to be outlined in light, giving away its exact position.  That's half the point of *glitterdust*.

(One could also make the argument that *glitterdust* is a spell effect and not really an object that can be turned invisible anyway.  I'm not sure it matters - it's dust, you can't really see the individual dust particles anyway, except for the fact they double as strobe lights.)

Comment: I always thought of it as glowing sticky flour. I agree the source of light is still there, but on a sunny day would you be able to notice that this area is producing light? In a dark cave you would easily know what square they are in.

Comment: I could see it being difficult in areas that were already bright light, that would be a very edge-case but fair houserule (since it would only apply if a new invisibility effect was applied to a *glitterdusted* target).  I mostly just think that it works exactly like a paper-thin, yellow *faerie fire* - you're left with a "shell" of golden light that perfectly outlines the target to the point of being able to see details and movement, hence completely negating the benefits of invisibility and permitting precision damage.

Comment: @Fering Note that glitterdust does not say that it requires darkness to work.